# How to persist a Firebase web SDK login in custom storage library?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I have an Electron app, And in Electron's rendering process it has
it's storage like (localStorage, sessionStorage), I also have a simple extension to install when the my Electron application starts.

The problem I have to log in again in this extension in order to meet my needs, because I assume that Electron has a different (localStorage, sessionStorage) for the installed extensions.

Is there a way to make Firebase persist the login state in custom storage like [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store)? So I don't need to log in again in the extension rendering process as well.

Comment: From a [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+persistence+electron), this looks promising: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/david-asher/electron-firebase/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did more research, and I figured that out. and I think it suites my needs. Thank you Frank! https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1874#issuecomment-549085119

Comment: Good to hear @ahmadbdw.  If you can write up what you did as an answer below, that might be helpful to others too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure! I'll do